# Drupal: how to set up multilanguage Drupal on several domains?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, multilingual, dns

I need to set up Drupal 6 as a multilanguage site.
1 installation, several language versions = several domains, i.e.

- English at `englishsite.com`
- French at `frenchsite.com`
- German at `germansite.com`.

I've found a [Tutorial](http://drupal-translation.com/content/using-different-domain-name-each-language) that suggest that you need **access to server's http.conf** - this is quite unlikely on shared hosting.
**Is it really neccesary?**

Maybe You can set it up with `.htaccess` or any other way.
Namely: **what should I do to have such a configuration working ?**
(after setting *Language negotiation* to *Domain name only* on `.../admin/settings/language/configure`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what I've found this could resolved in at least 2 ways.

#### Admin interface

Make the domains point to the Drupal directory in the hosting account admin interface (what is equivalent to http.conf edit suggestion from the tutorial)

#### Symbolic links

Replace the domain-specific directories with [symbolic links](http://man-wiki.net/index.php/1:ln) to the Drupal directory (in Unix-based systems), i.e.
`ln -s <drupalDirectory> <domainDirectoryName>`